# Error to variable transition on other page

Tags: ios, swift, xcode11

I'm creating a greeting app that users can enter their names and the app return `"Hello Jack!"`.

**Error Message**

```
Type 'UIViewController' has no member 'textFieldString'
```

How can I fix it, since I have already setted the variable on ViewController.swift.

```
        textFieldString = textField.text!
```

**Codes**

ViewController.swift

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    [![enter image description here][1]][1]
    var textFieldString = ""

    @IBAction func pushButton(_ sender: UIButton){
        textFieldString = textField.text!
        textField.text = ""
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let resultViewController = segue.destination as! ResultViewController
        resultViewController.result = textFieldString
    }

    @IBAction func unwind(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

    }



}
```

ResultViewController.swift

```swift
import UIKit

class ResultViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    var result: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

               label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
               label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
               label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
               label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
               label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

        label.text = "Hello\(result)! "
           }
}
```

**Screenshots**
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: the error text speaks completely about your problem - `UIViewController.textFieldString` - it's an issue. I'd recommend to set your variable `resultViewController.label.text = textField.text`  here `override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Reason:**

`textFieldString` is a property of `ViewController` and not `UIViewController`.

**Solution:**

Create a property `result` in `ResultViewController` and set it to `label` in `viewDidLoad()`.

```
class ResultViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    var result: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //rest of the code...
        label.text = "Hello\(result ?? "")" //here...
    }
}
```

Now in `ViewController's` `prepare(for:sender:)` method set `result` to `textFieldString`, i.e.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let resultViewController = segue.destination as! ResultViewController
    resultViewController.result = textField.text
}
```

Comment: The current output on the seond page.
```
HelloOptional("")!
```

I wrote `label.text = "Hello\(result)! "` but I cannot see the result given from the textform.

Comment: What is the text that you entered in the textField? Do add the screenshot at well.

Comment: @NPP Updated the code. Don't use `!` too extensively. It might result in unnecessary crash.

Comment: Even I chaneged to `label.text = "Hello\(result)"`, I have recieved `HelloOptional("")`.
```
String interpolation produces a debug description for an optional value; did you mean to make this explicit?

Use 'String(describing:)' to silence this warning
Provide a default value to avoid this warning
```

Comment: @NPP I've use `label.text = "Hello\(result ?? "")"` in the answer. `result` is an optional, so `??` returns an unwrapped or default value.

Comment: `label.text = "Hello\(result ?? "")"`case, only "Hello" has been shown.

Comment: That's because prepare(for:sender:) is called before the button action method.

Comment: @NPP Set `resultViewController.result = textField.text` instead of `textFieldString`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to perform a segue with your previous ViewController as destination.

like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let destination = segue.destination as? ViewController
    destination?.textField.text = "Hello Jack"
}
```

Comment: "Hello Jack" worked if I wrote `label.text = "Hello Jack"`, but still I'm stucked with transition of the value of variable.

Comment: @NPP try to pass the textBox.Text straight to the next view and not assigning to a variable

Answer (score 0):

Hey @NPP I have checked all your code same you written i can send you the code sample also if you needed. Your problem is that you did not connected your IBOutlet to your textfield.

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
```

This is your IBOutlet please connect it to the text field in your storyboard.

Thanks